# Transitive form of "to be"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there a single word in English that means something like "is-ify" or "to confer the property of existence"?

I am not looking for "create."

Comment: Can you clarify why "create" doesn't work for you? It's the word that is traditionally used, for example, for the description in Genesis of God "conferring the property of existence" on things...

Comment: I can't use create because it's for a theological article where "create" is a technical term.

Comment: *instantiate* works in some cases, as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Synonyms of *create* include *produce*, *make*, *engender*, *generate*, … In formal writing, you might also use ***reify***.

Comment: Ah, _reify_, that's the one I couldn't think of!

Comment: Thanks. I'll go with reify though I should probably define it in a footnote or something.

Answer (score 6):

*Embody* or *engender* might work in a theological context.

Answer (score 6):

"Realise" (though its more common meaning of "come to understand" may get in the way)